# PHP class name as a string

Tags: php, class

Is there a built-in static method or property to refer to a PHP class so that it will contextually be represented as a string?  For example:

Instead of this:

```
$obj->tempFn('MyClass') //MyClass being the name of the class
```

I want to do this:

```
$obj->tempFn(MyClass) //Directly references the class name, instead of a string representation
```

Comment: $obj->tempFn(new MyClass())

or

$myClass = new MyClass();
//do something with this object

$obj->tempFn($myClass);

Comment: Note that new MyClass() creates an instance of the class MyClass, its not the same as a reference to a class. But why would you need to do this anyway?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "contextually be represented as a string". What are you attempting to do? The question can interpreted in a few ways.

Comment: I'd like to do it this way because it would be a clean, direct reference to the class instead of a string (where human error can cause issue and the IDE can't detect that it's a reference to an actual class).  I want the result to be a string but without directly typing a string.  Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: @Sverri: OP is trying to get the fully qualified class name. This is useful when you use namespaces and you want to pass the class name to a function or something. When using strings, you're forced to prepend the namespace too :(

Comment: You can always check the type of the object by `$obj instanceof MyClass`.

Comment: @OneTrickPony Okay. Fully qualified class name. From how the question is worded I was going in the type-hinting direction, and that he wanted to know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. But you can define a constant in your class, that contains the class name, like:

```
class foo{
  const  
    NAME = 'foo';
}
```

And access it like `foo::NAME`.

In [PHP 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars), you'll be able to use:

```
foo::class
```

Comment: That was the approach I was going to take, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way.  Surprised it's not already available.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`echo get_class($this);`should work inside of a class.

`echo __CLASS__;` I believe this is a static property

Comment: Thank you, but I need to refer to it outside of the class itself and without instantiating the class first.

Comment: You can return the `__CLASS__` property inside a static method (i.e. static function getName())?

Comment: @astonius is this a joke? If you dont instantiate the class, you can access it only via static methods and variables. To access static things you must know the name of the class. Like `Math::sum()`. Just write manually `echo "Math"`??

Comment: @Husman `Math::getName()` returns `Math`. The same as `Husman! What's your name? -Husman...` :DDD

Comment: @Jari Yep, it does, you have your thinking hat on today, but that was what was asked for. "I need to refer to it outside of the class itself and without instantiating the class first"

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to create a static method or const for every single class, but it's looking like that's the approach I have to take.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If really wanting to avoid the statics I think the Reflection class might work.

```
function getClassName(ReflectionParameter $param) {
    preg_match('/\[\s\<\w+?>\s([\w]+)/s', $param->__toString(), $matches);
    return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : null;
}
```

That's from the comments on http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getclass.php